# How can I fully parse json into ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm parsing a mongodb input into logstash, the config file is as follows:

```
input {
    mongodb {
        uri => "<mongouri>"
        placeholder_db_dir => "<path>"
        collection => "modules"
        batch_size => 5000
    }
}
filter {
        mutate  {
            rename => { "_id" => "mongo_id" }
            remove_field => ["host", "@version"]
        }
        json   {
            source => "message"
            target => "log"
        } 
}
output {
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            action => "index"
            index => "mongo_log_modules"
        }
}
```

Outputs 2/3 documents from the collection into elasticsearch.

```
{
    "mongo_title" => "user",
      "log_entry" => "{\"_id\"=>BSON::ObjectId('60db49309fbbf53f5dd96619'), \"title\"=>\"user\", \"modules\"=>[{\"module\"=>\"user-dashboard\", \"description\"=>\"User Dashborad\"}, {\"module\"=>\"user-assessment\", \"description\"=>\"User assessment\"}, {\"module\"=>\"user-projects\", \"description\"=>\"User projects\"}]}",
       "mongo_id" => "60db49309fbbf53f5dd96619",
        "logdate" => "2021-06-29T16:24:16+00:00",
    "application" => "mongo-modules",
     "@timestamp" => 2021-10-02T05:08:38.091Z
}
{
    "mongo_title" => "candidate",
      "log_entry" => "{\"_id\"=>BSON::ObjectId('60db49519fbbf53f5dd96644'), \"title\"=>\"candidate\", \"modules\"=>[{\"module\"=>\"candidate-dashboard\", \"description\"=>\"User Dashborad\"}, {\"module\"=>\"candidate-assessment\", \"description\"=>\"User assessment\"}]}",
       "mongo_id" => "60db49519fbbf53f5dd96644",
        "logdate" => "2021-06-29T16:24:49+00:00",
    "application" => "mongo-modules",
     "@timestamp" => 2021-10-02T05:08:38.155Z
}
```

Seems like the output of stdout throws un-parsable code into

> "log_entry"

After adding "rename" fields "modules" won't add a field.

I've tried the grok mutate filter, but after the _id %{DATA}, %{QUOTEDSTRING} and %{WORD} aren't working for me.

I've also tried updating a nested mapping into the index, didn't seem to work either

Is there anything else I can try to get the FULLY nested code into elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to filter with mutate

```
mutate { gsub => [ "log_entry", "=>", ": " ] }
mutate { gsub => [ "log_entry", "BSON::ObjectId\('([0-9a-z]+)'\)", '"\1"' ]}
json { source => "log_entry" remove_field => [ "log_entry" ] }
```

Outputs to stdout

```
       "_id" => "60db49309fbbf53f5dd96619",
     "title" => "user",
   "modules" => [
    [0] {
             "module" => "user-dashboard",
        "description" => "User Dashborad"
    },
    [1] {
             "module" => "user-assessment",
        "description" => "User assessment"
    },
    [2] {
             "module" => "user-projects",
        "description" => "User projects"
    }
],
```